# c# Check if any picture applied

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I'm trying to show an image from a folder that the user selected.and if he slected a record that does not have any picture, it would show an image which is called

> Empty.png

here's the code i wrote. how can i change it that it will fit what i wrote in the explaination?(the top of this question)

```
            string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Projects_2012\Project_Noam\Files\ProteinPic");

            foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            {
                if (fileName.Contains(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()))
                {
                    Image image = Image.FromFile(fileName);
                    // Set the PictureBox image property to this image.
                    // ... Then, adjust its height and width properties.
                    pictureBox1.Image = image;
                    pictureBox1.Height = image.Height;
                    pictureBox1.Width = image.Width;
                }
            }
```

Comment: what does it means "record that does not have any picture" ? Do you want to know if fileName is image ?

Comment: the user choose a record in comboBox.it the isn't for the specific record he choose a picture, show "empty" picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to iterate through every file in the directory to acheive what you want

```
        Image image;

        string imagePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Projects_2012\Project_Noam\Files\ProteinPic", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(imagePath))
        {
            image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
        }
        else
        {
            image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Projects_2012\Project_Noam\Files\ProteinPic\Empty.png");
        }

        pictureBox1.Image = image;
        pictureBox1.Height = image.Height;
        pictureBox1.Width = image.Width;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
{
   if (fileName.Contains(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()))
   {
     pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(fileName);              
   }
   else
   {
     pictureBox1.Image = ImageFromFile("Empty.png");                
   }

   // Set the PictureBox image property to this image.
   // ... Then, adjust its height and width properties.
   pictureBox1.Image = image;
   pictureBox1.Height = image.Height;
   pictureBox1.Width = image.Width;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Projects_2012\Project_Noam\Files\ProteinPic");

        if (fileEntries.Length == 0)
        {
            Image image = Image.FromFile("Path of empty.png");
            pictureBox1.Image = image;
            pictureBox1.Height = image.Height;
            pictureBox1.Width = image.Width;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            {
                if (fileName.Contains(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()))
                {
                    Image image = Image.FromFile(fileName);
                    pictureBox1.Image = image;
                    pictureBox1.Height = image.Height;
                    pictureBox1.Width = image.Width;
                }
            }
        }
```